# How to use label filter on intermediate containers that get created during build (assuming LABEL is set immediately after FROM command)?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image, docker-build

In the dockerfile, suppose I set a LABEL immediately after the FROM command, then is the label applied to every intermediate container and image generated in the subsequent step?

I know that intermediate containers get removed during build after each step. But I am facing an issue where-in some of the intermediate container are not getting removed. This is causing the images created out of these containers (during the build process) to become dangled.

I can see the images in `docker images` and containers in `docker ps -aq`.

I am trying to filter them to get a list - with eventual goal to prune the images. Filter to get list of images based on LABEL: `docker images --filter "label=some-key=some-value"` - this shows me the images that I wish to prune. But before that I need to stop/prune those containers created from the above images. Filter to get list based on LABEL - `docker ps --filter "label=some-key=some-value"`, but it doesn't return me the container (no value is returned).

When I do `docker inspect <container-id>`, then I can see label ("some-key"="some-value") in the Config section, under Labels. How can I filter the container based on this label?

Comment: why don't you use `-f dangling=true`?

Comment: What purpose will that serve? The question is to filter a container based on label!

Comment: well you said `with eventual goal to prune the image`, that's what `-f dangling=true` will do.