# What is the best practice to prune dangled images and its associated container(s) based on image label?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I have couple of dangled images (images that appear in `docker images` with none tag). To clean them, based on LABEL, the usual command is: `docker image prune -a --force --filter="label=some-key=some-value"`.

However, this command doesn't prune dangled images that have container associated. Irrespective of whether the container is started or stopped.

I cannot run `docker container prune -f` since I don't want to prune all stopped containers. Is there a command to prune images and the containers associated with the image **based on image label**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker remove <none> TAG images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913020/docker-remove-none-tag-images)

Comment: Remove only dangling images: ```docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)```

Comment: You cannot apply rmi on the dangled image which is being used by a container

Comment: Can you just filter the results from `docker ps -aq` and use that to prune the unneeded containers? Like `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq --filter=...)`?

Comment: Filter based on? And is that a Linux or PowerShell or cross platform command?

Comment: Whatever you want, I assumed from your question you had some filter in mind. Ex. `docker ps -aq --filter="label=com.docker.compose.service=redis"` gives me all the containers started by compose for redis, ready for pruning

Comment: My container doesn't have the label- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794023/how-to-use-label-filter-on-intermediate-containers-that-get-created-during-build

Answer (score 0):

Given an image (or images) with a label, you want to delete any containers using that image.

Using `xargs` and the `ancestor` filter, you can do that:

```
docker image ls -q --filter "label=foo=bar" | \
    xargs -I IMG docker ps -aq --filter "ancestor=IMG" | \
    xargs docker rm -fv
```

It's not exactly "one command" but it should get you where you need to go.

Or Powershell:

```
@(docker image ls -q --filter "label=foo=bar") | %{&"docker" ps -qa --filter "ancestor=$_"} | %{&"docker" rm -fv $_}
```